# Sci-Fi episode where half of the people are kept in stasis

Tags: story-identification, movie, stasis

This must be real easy if someone knows the title, but google searching for the plot is pretty much useless - I tried it for an hour and still nothing.

It’s about a dystopian world with too many people and not enough resources.
Therefore a elite group decided to put half of the working population in stasis. 2 people have the same room (accommodation), the same stasis chamber and the same job but are only "awake" half the time and only see each other in person when changing.
Two of them fall in love.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: Very recently … must be quite new but for some reason I can’t remember the title or any name of an actor.

Comment: Was the stasis chamber positioned vertically or horizontally? Also, was the film in English or another language?

Comment: Horizontal. The two main characters only met when one of them left the stasis and the other had to "go in".  It was certainly an English movie but available in dubbed versions as well.

Comment: This sounds similar to the arrangement in Philip Jose Farmer's _Dayworld_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is **"[Stasis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667954/)"**, S06E09 of *[The Outer Limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series))* (1995-2002).

From the [The Outer Limits Wiki](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/Stasis):

> In a future world of scarce resources, the world government regulates the population into two working classes (Alphas and Betas) in order to maximize conservation. These two classes rotate in and out of suspended animation for 72-hour periods. But what happens when an Alpha and a Beta fall in love with each other and never see each other face-to-face except for shift changes?

The story is set in a futuristic society where workers are divided into two groups who take turns going into suspended animation for 72-hour periods. There's also a class of people who manage this system and aren't required to go into stasis themselves, referred to as the Elite.

The main characters are a man and a woman who share the same quarters and work in the same role, maintaining infrastructure such as control valves. They leave recorded messages to update one another on their progress, and only see each other in person, briefly, when it's time to switch places in their shared stasis pod, which is located in a large communal area occupied by many such pods.

They develop feelings for one another, and express this through their recorded messages and by leaving things (such as candlelit dinners and roses) for each other in their shared quarters, but feel the need to hide this from everyone else due to the oppressive nature of their society.

Comment: Yes … of course. ‍♂️ -  Thank you!   -  Somehow my brain mixed this Outer Limits story with another (more recent) movie.